Why is this almost complex structure integrable?
I am reading this paper by Taubes, and I am having trouble understanding the following construction. The setup is as follows:

$(X, \omega)$ is a symplectic $4$-manifold;
$J$ is a compatible almost complex structure on $X$;
$g$ is the Riemannian metric $g = \omega(\cdot, J(\cdot))$;
$C$ is a pseudo-holomorphic submanifold of $X$ (i.e., a $2$-dimensional submanifold whose tangent spaces are complex subspaces);
$N = N_C$ is the normal bundle of $C$ with respect to the metric $g$.

Here is the passage that confuses me:

The bundle $N$ inherits the structure of a holomorphic vector bundle over $C$. The point here is that the Levi-Civita connection for the metric $g$ induces a connection on $N_C$ which decomposes $T(N_C)$ as $p^*(TC \oplus N_C)$. Here, $p : N_C \to C$ is the bundle projection. But, as remarked, the almost complex structure $J|_C$ preserves the splitting in (1.4) and so its pull-back to $T(N_C)$ defines an almost complex structure, $J_0$, on $TN_C$ which is invariant under translations along the fiber and preserves the connection splitting.
The almost complex structure $J_0$ is integrable and so $N_C$ has the structure of a complex manifold. This is to say that $J_0$ gives the complex line bundle $N$ the structure of a holomorphic vector bundle over the complex curve $C$. Note in particular, that the fibers of $N$ are $J_0$-holomorphic lines in $N$.

I have the following questions:

What is the connection on $N_C$ induced by the Levi-Civita connection for $g$? Is it the composition
$$
\Gamma(N_C) \to \Gamma(TX|_C) \xrightarrow{\nabla} \Gamma(T^*C \otimes TX|_C) \to \Gamma(T^*C \otimes N_C),
$$
where the last term is given by orthogonal projection?
Why is $J_0$ integrable?


$J_0$ is integrable because $J|_C$ is integrable (since all almost complex structures on $C$ are integrable), and because $J_0$ is invariant under translations along the fibre. So in local coordinates, this invariance implies that $J_0$ is a product of an integrable complex structure, and a linear complex structure. You can show this is again integrable.
